# How to set up Dave Raggett's HTML Tidy on Windows?

Tags: html, tidy

I'm having a hard time looking for an easy to understand instruction to download, set up and use this HTML Tidy by [Dave Raggett](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/).
Please help, I need this kind of tool that can almost perfectly scan html errors.
If there is a GUI version for the latest one, please share the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click the link to the downloads
2. Pick binary executables
3. [select a version suitable for your edition of Windows](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#binaries)

Comment: Windows GUI version doesn't recognize some html tags like `<header>`. What can you suggest? Thanks

Comment: one last question, how can I use it in windows? Thanks

Comment: Get the source. Get gmake. Try to build it. Patch it if you need to. (It is an experimental fork to add support for a draft spec, it is not a polished product). Alternatively, install Linux (even if only within a VM).

Comment: Has anyone succeded building tidy for windows, especially as a library?

Answer (score 2):

A precompiled Windows binary for the [experimental HTML5-fork](http://w3c.github.com/tidy-html5/) can be found at http://tidybatchfiles.info/.